# max(DF1$EFFDT) <= DF2$EFFDT

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have two dataframes, DF1 containing monthly data snapshot of data whereas DF2 with a particular date and i want to be able to retrieve data only for closest maxdate (<=) from DF1 wrt DF2 data.

DF1

| Account | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A1000001 | 1-JAN-2021 |
| A1000002 | 1-FEB-2021 |
| A1000003 | 1-MAR-2021 |
| A1000004 | 1-APR-2021 |

DF2

| Date |
| --- |
| 15-MAR-2021 |

Output Expected:

| Account | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A1000003 | 1-MAR-2021 |

Answer (score 0):

Change the dates to actual date class and using `sapply` you may find the closest date in `df1` for each date in `df2`.

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, '%d-%b-%Y')
df2$Date <- as.Date(df2$Date, '%d-%b-%Y')
result <- df1[sapply(df2$Date, function(x) which.min(abs(df1$Date - x))), ]
result

#   Account       Date
#3 A1000003 2021-03-01
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Account = c("A1000001", "A1000002", "A1000003", 
"A1000004"), Date = c("1-JAN-2021", "1-FEB-2021", "1-MAR-2021", 
"1-APR-2021")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Date = "15-MAR-2021"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
class = "data.frame")
```